# Page which has master does not work with or without <form runat=server> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I try to publish a C#/ASP.NET page and receive the following error message:

> Control XXX must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

When I add the `<form runat="server">` tag, I receive the following error:

> A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

I know that my master page has the `runat=server` form tag and that the content is encompassed within that tag. I also see that the error appears to be occuring within

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a05ad405\1aeb0277\App_Web_lgjjhruj.3.cs:0

which is I suppose a temporary file?

My question is, has anyone had a similar error and how was it resolved?

Comment: Could you post some example code, maybe the placement of the form tag and contentplaceholders is not quite correct.

Comment: After deleting all temp files and republishing it went through.  Looks like it was just a cached page issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep Only one  in master page
Remove all the form tag from content page,
as well as head and body tag from content page.

and most importantly keep all the controls inside the content place holder that will be rendered inside form tag.

put run at server in all asp controls.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another form inside of your content page (which uses your master page)? You should have a form which runs at server only in your masterpage. Search your project (ctrl + shift + f) for

Comment: No, there is only one in the Master page and when I put one in the content page I get the second error.  When I remove it I get the first error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your MasterPage and make sure all controls with a `runat="server"` are contained within the `<form runat="server">` element.

Comment: I have <form runat="server"> as the outermost element for that reason.